# Randomly round to integer in Excel

Tags: excel, random, excel-formula, rounding

Is there a way in Excel to randomly round up or down a float to an integer number? Possibly with 50% chance of rounding up.

Something like:

```
ROUND_RANDOM(3.6,0) = 3

ROUND_RANDOM(3.6,0) = 4

ROUND_RANDOM(3.6,0) = 4

ROUND_RANDOM(3.6,0) = 3
```

Comment: Well you could include a 50% chance using `RANDBETWEEN()`. For example: `=IF(RANDBETWEEN(0,1),ROUNDDOWN(3.6,0),ROUNDUP(3.6,0))`

Comment: Or even round(random(3,6),0) but then you can add a random function to choose between a roundup, round or rounddown...

Comment: This is the same as always rounding down and then randomly adding either 0 or 1.  Which is a much easier problem to solve.

Comment: @MikeNakis, that's right. It would boil down to: `=RANDBETWEEN(0,1)+ROUNDDOWN(A$1,0)`. Put an answer down?

Comment: @JvdV nah, I did not know enough excel (by heart) to provide the actual solution. You can go ahead and answer it if you want.

Comment: @MikeNakis: Is it the same? For an exact integer, `ROUNDDOWN` and `ROUNDUP` would give the same result, so randomly choosing between them isn't the same as rounding down and randomly adding `0` or `1`.

Comment: @MarkDickinson I am not sure. You might be right.  Then again, exact integers tend to be rare. I guess it depends on the OP's application.